# How do you add a new device to an ad hoc distribution profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've added some new devices to the development portal and want to be able to send them an ad-hoc distribution for installation via iTunes.

However I can't see anywhere on portal website where devices can be added to the ad-hoc profile.
I've tried refreshing the profiles via XCode, and that added the new devices to other profiles but it didn't add them to the ad-hoc profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an "Edit" button on the right side of your Ad-hoc profile listing, click that and use the checkboxes to select the devices you want on this profile.

[image: Edit button]

Comment: in mine is written "managed by XCode" and I can't edit it from there.. any suggestions?

Comment: @mm24 That's probably your development profile. Switch tabs to distribution profiles.

Comment: Yeah, managed. I wasn't that familiar. I also realized how easy is to then update the distribution profile via XCode (just clicking on refresh code signing identities). When I started learning iOS development it took me some days, now a little bit less :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Log into the provisioning portal at http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action

- Go to distribution tab.
- Find your ad-hoc provisioning profile
- Hit edit.
- Tick the new device in the list thats shown (or choose 'select all').
- Profile will say pending.
- wait a few seconds, reload.
- Download and install new profile.